# Importing file from parent folder

Tags: python, python-import

My folder structure is as follows:

```
parent_folder
├── folder
│   └── file.ipynb
└── LEID.py
```

I would like to import a function named LEID in LEID.py to file.ipynb

What I have tried:

```
from LEID import LEID
```

doesn't work

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path_to_parent_folder')
from parent_folder.LEID import LEID
```

doesn't work

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, 'path_to_LEID.py')
from LEID import LEID
```

doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the second method would have worked if I included '/' at the end of the directory.

```
import sys 

sys.path.append('C:/folder_containing_my_module/') # works

sys.path.append('C:/folder_containing_my_module') # doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Andrew Ryan's comment, you could try something like below:

```
import os
import sys
import inspect

currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.insert(0, parentdir) 

from LEID import LEID
```

That should help to get the pathing right between file references

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried your code, I can see correct syntax highlighting in "from LEID import LEID" but still returns "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'LEID'". Anyway I gave up this method, now I just import module using the full path as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-do-i-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)